# Just tried smth simple with pointers in C and it is confusing

Tags: c, pointers

I wanted to explore what happens, if you pass a value to the address of a pointer without declaring the address itself before. After the declaration I assigned the address of `a` as a value for the pointer itself. When I print now the value of `a`, I always get `8` as an output, no matter if I change the datatype or the value of `*ptr`. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
  int a, *ptr = 190;
  ptr = &a;
  printf(%d, a);
  return 0;
 }
```

OUTPUT:
8

Little correction: The datatype does matter, with char and short, I get always `0`. With `int`, `long int` and so on, I get always `8`. And with `double`, I get `4200624`. It is still confusing.

Comment: That program will not give any output at all, since it won't build.

Comment: *However* your "problem" have nothing to do with pointers, but rather that you print the value of the *uninitialized* variable `a`. As it is uninitialized its value will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random.

Comment: If you want to print the pointer value, then you should print `ptr`, not `a`.  You can use `printf("%p\n", (void *)ptr);`

Comment: but if it is really random, why can I rewrite it and get still the same output?

Comment: **Furthermore** if you program in C++ even *reading* an uninitialized local variable will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which makes your whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite it"? Also note that I said "**seemingly** random".

Comment: It's not random, it's just unspecified.  Please don't post questions about why undefined behavior happens to do one thing or another.  You're probably just picking up some previous value that happened to be on the stack.  Is that useful to you?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - an ill-formed program is one for which the standard requires an implementation to issue a diagnostic.   Undefined behaviour does not make a program ill-formed.

Comment: @Peter You're correct. To late to edit my comment now though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh sorry, i overread the seemingly.

Comment: I still have not understanded it completely, but thanks for trying to help me. Time will make me wiser. ^^

Comment: @s0mbre the value `a` is not initialized, but it is in memory that has already been used by something else. `main` is not where the program actually starts running, there are things that happen before that set things up so that you can use thing like printf and such. That code will use some memory. That memory is reused by `a`. What things happen before `main` depend on the rest of your code, if not for other reasons, just for the fact that the size of the code changes and things are put in different places in memory. That's why the uninitialized value of `a` might change, or not.

Comment: Always copy/paste the code that you actually tested, else you will likely get your questions dowvoted/closed.

Answer (score 0):

`int a, *ptr = 190;` must normally throw, at least, a warning at compile time, because you tried to assign an `int` value to initialize a pointer. On my compiler I got:

```
a.c:3:11: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
      'int *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
  int a, *ptr = 190;
          ^     ~~~
```

It is probably not what you wanted, assigning a fixed value to a pointer is of very specific usage.

`printf(%d, a);` is an error as `printf` first argument must be a `char *`. You probably wanted to write `printf("%d"...)`. My compiler said:

```
a.c:5:10: error: expected expression
  printf(%d, a);
         ^
```

Even in this case the whole program as *undefined behavior* because you are trying to read a variable (`a` through the pointer `ptr`) that was not assigned before.

You probably wanted to write something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a, *ptr;// definition of two variables, one of type int, one of type pointer to int, both non initialized
  ptr = &a;   // ptr points to variable a (contains its address)
  *ptr = 190; // assignment of the variable pointed by ptr
  printf("%d\n", a); // should print 190 as the content of a has been previously assigned
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot the char in printf. Didnt copypaste the code bcs it were just a few lines. But my basic idea and question was, what happens if u switch the lines 4 and 5 in your code. And the result confused me.